# Two inputs with one way binding in ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-ngmodel

I try to make an application which have two inputs text (say parent and child) , each one has `ng-model` .

I want to make it one way binding , mean , change in the parent input should display the same value in the child , and change in the child input wouldn't affect in the parent .

please try to make it as Angular solution as can (avoid key event .. )

Here is my code so far , changing in the parent cause to change in the child but it break the binding once I typing in the child -

```js
var myAppModule = angular.module('myApp', []) 
  .controller('myCtrl',function ($scope) {
   $scope.myText = "Type your text"
         
     })
     .directive('myDrtv',function () {
         return {
          restrict: 'A',
          scope: {
           myText: '='/* =/@/&*/
          },
          template: "<input type='text' ng-value='myText' style='margin-left:64px'>",
          link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
          }
         }
     })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <input type="text" ng-model="myText">
  <div my-drtv my-text="myText"/>
 </div>
```

Comment: How can an input element have an input child element ? Anyway, you could use something like ng-keypress="updateMySecondModelFunction", that would update the second $scope variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You could simply update your "child" model on `ng-keypress`** (on the parent):

JS:

```
var myAppModule = angular.module('myApp', []) 
    .controller('myCtrl',function ($scope) {
        $scope.myText = "Type your text"
        $scope.myChildText = $scope.myText;
        $scope.updateChildText = function (){
          $scope.myChildText = $scope.myText;
        }
    })
    .directive('myDrtv',function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: {
                myText: '='/* =/@/&*/
            },
            template: "<input ng-model="myChildText" type='text' style='margin-left:64px'>",
            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            }
        }
    });
```

HTML :

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <input type="text" ng-keypress="updateChildText" ng-model="myText">
    <div my-drtv my-text="myText"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can setup a watcher to set second input value manually:

```
.directive('myDrtv', function() {
    return {
        scope: {
            myText: '='
        },
        template: "<input type='text'>",
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var input = element.find('input');
            scope.$watch('myText', function(newVal) {
                input.val(newVal);
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/60ZQHZQq14A6qkUxbTRO?p=info

Answer (score 0):

**One way Binding with directive**

This created from above one . but this example not used DOM access . it is pure angularjs code . it may help you.

live code http://plnkr.co/edit/hs7VTZfHmvMcVv5nHLCE?p=preview

```
app.directive('myDrtv', function() {
    return {
        scope: {
            myText: '='
        },
        template: "<input type='text' ng-model='myChild'>",
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$watch('myText', function(newVal) {
               scope.myChild = scope.myText;
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: it will help you access child text box by ng-model name

Comment: @dfsq .., your answer is superb

Answer (score 0):

I would use the ngModelController instead.

```js
var myAppModule = angular.module('myApp', []) 
  .controller('myCtrl',function ($scope) {
   $scope.myText = "Type your text"
         
     })
     .directive('myDrtv',function () {
           return {
               scope: {
                   myText: '='
               },
               template: "<input type='text' ng-value='myText' style='margin-left:64px'>",
               require: '?ngModel', // get a hold of NgModelController
               link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
                  var input = element.find('input');
      
                  ngModel.$render = function() {
                    input.val(ngModel.$viewValue);
                  };
               }
           }
        })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <input type="text" ng-model="myText">
  <div my-drtv ng-model="myText"></div>
 </div>
```